# Html.BeginForm passing Model item value

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Am using mvc4 and am calling another controller in my view using Html.BeginForm

It work fine!but here am using textbox to pass the value.
How to modify this code so am using

> @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
>   ....instead of 
>   @Html.TextBox("UserName")

here my view  :

image of it:[image]

```
                     @using OTMS.Models
        @model IEnumerable<OTMS.Models.UserProfile>

        @{
           ViewBag.Title = "Index";
        }

                <!-- Table Continer -->
        <div class="spacer_10px"></div>
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="grid_12"> 
               <div class="table_wrapper table_gray">
        <table>

             <tr>
                <th>
                   <p>User Name</p>
                </th>
                 <th>
                   <p>Role</p>
                </th>
                 <th>
                   <p>Role</p>
                </th>
            </tr>


            @if (Model != null) {
        foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>


            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>

            <td>
              @using(Html.BeginForm("GetRoles", "Account",FormMethod.Post)){
              @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="editor-label">Username : </div>
             @Html.TextBox("UserName") //here user will enter user name / I dont want user to enter that ,it should be done Automatically 



                  <div class="spacer_20px"></div>
                  <div class="button button-orange"> <span class=" form_button clearfix">
                  <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Get Roles for this User" />
                  </span> </div>//by clicking that will pass the user name to controller (GerRole)/I dont want  button
        }


            </td>

            <td>

               @using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "Account", FormMethod.Post))
           {
                     @Html.Hidden("userName", item.UserName)

                     @Html.DropDownList("selectedRole", (SelectList)ViewBag.Roles)

                     <div class="button button-orange"> <span class=" form_button clearfix">
                    <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Update Change" />
                    </span> </div>
            }

            </td>
        </tr>

        }
            }
             </table>
                 </div> </div>
```

here my controller :

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = _db.UserProfiles.ToList();

        ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
        {
            ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName);
            SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
            ViewBag.Roles = list;


        }
        return View("showrole");
    }
```

another view:

image of it :
[image]

```
            @{
                ViewBag.Title = "showrole";
            }

            <h2>showrole</h2>
            @if(ViewBag.RolesForThisUser != null) {
                <text>
                <h3>Roles for this user </h3>
                <ol>
            @foreach (string s in ViewBag.RolesForThisUser){
                <li>@s</li>   
            }
                            </ol>
                </text>
            }
```

Comment: Why do you want to use @Html.DisplayFor? Why not @Html.EditorFor?

Comment: i want to show the value only ..without input field and without submit button ..

Comment: It's not clear for me what you want to archieve. You want the form which is calling another controller, but you don't want submit button, but how do you plan to post data to controller? Or the code with @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName) is not working and you are wondering how to use it rightly?

Comment: no the code working see Q again I update it .am using submit button to go to another view  ..and I dont want that I want to show them in the table and same view and I dont know how!

Comment: It seems that I understand what you are trying to archeive. Bassically you want to get rid of Get roles for this user button and just make the third column work. It's important to know if you have role or roles for current user inside UserProfile when you are quering it with _db.UserProfiles.ToList()?

Comment: see in the third colum am changing the role of users(it work fine) .Now I only need to show in second colum(what is the current role).Now as my code above am doing that but by submit button to another view(showrole view)and i dont want that .I want to display the current role simply in the third colum of the table and that it ,

Comment: do you have the current role field in OTMS.Models.UserProfile? or the only way to know current role is to call Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName)?

Comment: yes this the only way Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName) :( ..

Comment: but you have _db.Roles, right? Or what does Roles.GetRolesForUser method call to get the roles for user?

Comment: default mvc4 template has simplermembership ..see this http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/show/2648/working-with-roles-in-aspnet-mvc-4

Comment: ok, now I understand what you are using. I've posted my answer, it should be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you definetely need to do is to create a view model for your view, for me it looks something like this:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public IEnumerable<string> UserRoles { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your index action you would return a list of these view models.
You certainly could do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = _db.UserProfiles.ToList()
                                .Select(u => new UserViewModel{
                                     UserName = u.UserName,
                                     UserRoles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(u.UserName)
                                                      .AsEnumerable()
                                })
                                .ToList();
    ViewBag.Roles = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
    return View(model);
}
```

but I wouldn't. It's because with this code you're doing one aditional query for every user just to get his roles. I think you need to add roles table to your EntityFramework model and try to do this with single query. So you need to extend your UserProfile with roles:

```
[Table("UserProfile")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

[Table("webpages_Roles")]
public class UserRoles
{
    [Key]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
}
```

Then update your DbContext with info about many to many relationship between UserProfils and UserRoles:

```
public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRoles>()
        .HasMany<UserProfile>(r => r.UserProfiles)
        .WithMany(u => u.UserRoles)
        .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("webpages_UsersInRoles");
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
        });
    }
}
```

After that in your index action - you can simply do:

```
    var model = _db.UserProfiles.Select(u => new UserViewModel()
    {
        UserName = u.UserName,
        UserRoles = u.UserRoles.Select(ur=>ur.RoleName)
    }).ToList();
```

And it will be one query instead of several in cycle.

EDIT:
Your model changed so you need to change `@model IEnumerable<OTMS.Models.UserProfile>` to `@model IEnumerable<OTMS.Models.UserViewModel>`
And then:

```
@foreach(var user in Model)
{
    //display user
    @foreach(var role in user.UserRoles)
    {
        //display roles with @role
    }
}
```

If you want to use DisplayTemplates - you can move logic for displying user into template. For this you need to create view by path 
**~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/UserViewModel.cshtml**

```
@model OTMS.Models.UserViewModel
//display user
@foreach(var role in user.UserRoles)
{
     //display roles with @role
}
```

then in Index.cshtml you can change code to this:

```
@foreach (var user in Model)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(n => user)
}
```

Comment: regards you first solutions.how do I present the roles in the view then ?

Comment: Updated my answer. See changes in EDIT section.

Comment: Oleksii Aza Thank you very much, Thank you ..I did the first solution :) ......you Know  today only I really know what the use of (viewModel).so it use when I want to combine 2 tables right ?

Comment: Generally speaking ViewModel is skeleton of your view. It could be combination of 2 tables, but sometimes it could get data from one table and just adapt it for view. For example: if you need page with just user names - you don't have to put whole IEnumerable<UserProfile> on the view. Better solutin is just create ViewModel, that contains IEnumerable<string> and project usernames into it.

Comment: Ok. one more Q for my submit button in thired colume am changing the user role and i can see the change in my Database but one I click it it will refresh the page ( but the table will be empty!).my code : public ActionResult Submit(string userName, string selectedRole)
        {
           //my logic
            return View("Index");
        }

Comment: The easiest way would be just return RedirectToAction("Index"); instead of View("Index");

Comment: I will appreciate if you fix the second solution ques ( is not showing UserRoles = u.UserRoles.Select(ur=>ur.RoleName) ..Thank you again

Comment: I'm sorry, don't understand what is wrong with second solution?

Comment: sorry I mixed up with others post..Am trying the second solution are you sure this line is correct  UserRoles = u.UserRoles.Select(ur=>ur.RoleName)?

Comment: absolutely, why are you asking?

Comment: is not working with me :( ..the first solution work but this one no .. I think the role table is somehow not linked..

Comment: I need that because am trying to do the same as you did ..but using Roles.GetUserInRoles ,so i should use your second solutions to work!

Comment: yah beforeso I delet the DB and creat again and it work then....conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles_dbo.webpages

Answer (score 0):

First and for All ,The Main Confusion is with this Helper..have a Breif Look here

- Use  `HiddenFor`  when you want to provide posted data that the user does not need to be aware of."
- Use `DisplayFor` when you want to show records but not allow them to be editted.
- Use `TextBoxFor` when you want to allow user input or allow the user to edit a field.
  `

Now your question is Like this..
`How can i use displayfor to hit my controller!!!!`

You could accomplish this with a duo of HiddenFor and DisplayFor. Use HiddenFor to have the values ready to be posted, and DisplayFor to show those values.

so to meet your Requirement

```
<div class="editor-label"> Username : </div>
@Html.TextBox("UserName")
```

Replace

```
<div class="editor-label"> Username : </div>
@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem=>item.username)
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.username)
```

Remember `Displayfor` Renders Only Label In the Browser,to post it back to Controller you need `HiddenFor`

Comment: this is not calling the the controller I post !

Comment: variable mismatch..edit your variable to one specified in the controller

Comment: I mean my parameter in controller is string UserName..where to put that in my view?

Comment: I update it Q .am using submit button to go to another view ..and I dont want that I want to show them in the table and same view and I dont know how!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

### Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetRoles(string UserName)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(UserName))
    {
        ViewBag.RolesForThisUser = Roles.GetRolesForUser(UserName);
        SelectList list = new SelectList(Roles.GetAllRoles());
        ViewBag.Roles = list;
    }
    return View("......");
}
```

### View

```
@ViewBag.Name
@using(Html.BeginForm("GetRoles", "Account")){
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="editor-label">Username : </div>
@Html.TextBox("UserName")
<div class="spacer_20px"></div>
<div class="button button-orange">
    <span class=" form_button clearfix">
        <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Get Roles for this User" />
    </span>
</div>
}
```

Here is the **<kbd>[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/XDj35U)</kbd>**

Comment: i want to show the value only ..without input field and without submit button ..and by calling the controller ..

Comment: what do you mean by that, do u need something like **[this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Yb2mf)**

Comment: see Q again I update it .am using submit button to go to another view ..and I don't want that I want to show them in the table and same view and I don't know how!